# Combining sections of xml from within the same file

Tags: xml, xquery, data-manipulation

I have an xml file that contains data from various tables in a VistaDB database which I wish to use to transfer data into a different VistaDB database.

The new database has a slightly different schema as it has become apparent that what at the time appeared to be a sensible data structure (based on inheritance) that would allow for further expansion across multiple subject areas wasn't going to work as intended.

As a result The xml file contains sections that represent the collected data from these tables, as illustrated below;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootElement>
    <Contact>
        <Oid>eeeba14b-ee5e-4051-aaea-686a4d79820e</Oid>
        <ContactNumber>CON0000003</ContactNumber>
        <ContactType>3</ContactType>
        <DefaultCurrency>0</DefaultCurrency>
    </Contact>
    <ContactBase>
        <Oid>eeeba14b-ee5e-4051-aaea-686a4d79820e</Oid>
        <CurrentBalance>-2757.52</CurrentBalance>
        <FirstInvoiceDate>2016-01-01T00:00:00+00:00</FirstInvoiceDate>
        <LastInvoiceDate>2019-04-18T15:48:51.7242817+01:00</LastInvoiceDate>
    </ContactBase>
    <CommonBase>
        <Oid>eeeba14b-ee5e-4051-aaea-686a4d79820e</Oid>
        <IsActive>true</IsActive>
        <ContactBusinessName>Fred Flintstone</ContactBusinessName>
    </CommonBase>
</RootElement>
```

Is there an easy way , perhaps using something like XQuery , with which I am not overly familiar, to effectively merge these separate sections into a single section using the common shared Oid element from within that one file or would it be easier to simply separate them out into fresh xml files and then merge them, a practice with which I am familiar and can do?

Comment: XQuery 3 has a `group by` clause https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-group-by that helps solving that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using `group by` in XQuery 3.1:

```
<RootElement>
{
    for $contact in RootElement/*
    group by $oid := $contact/Oid
    return
        <Contact>
        {
            head($contact)/Oid,
            $contact/(* except Oid)
        }
        </Contact>
}    
</RootElement>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8r

Comment: Worked beautifully, and taught me a good deal more about XQuery into the bargain, thanks.